# Log file not stored

Tags: database

I need to do research about log files not stored in the database. I  do not know much about database systems so i need someone to give at least some ideas about it. What i was told is that some of the log files was not written in a bank's database.Log files are coming from various sources like atms,website vs. For example, the reason could be high rate of data flow causing some data to be left out.
The question is what are the reasons behind it and what could be the solutions to them?
I would really appreciate if you could share some articles about it.
Sorry if i could not explain it well. Thanks in advance

Edit:what i meant was not there is a system not writing some of log files to database intentionally. What i tried to mean is that some of the log files are not written into database and the reason is not known and my intention is to identify the possible reasons and solutions to them.the database belongs to a bank and as you can imagine, lots of data is flowing to database per second

Comment: This is a very vague question. For starters, what DBMS are you even talking about ?

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Is it a system your designing and you want to consider storing the log in a DBMS? Or is it an existing system - that you can't find where the log files are stored? Can you edit the question and phrase it in a way that each person who reads it - would understand it the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the questions is not very clear, so let me rephrase it:

What are the reasons why application logs are not stored in a database

It depends of the context, and there are different reasons:

First question, is why you might store logs in database? Usually you do it because they contains relevant data to you that you want to manipulate.

So why not store always these datas:

- you are not interested by the log, except when something goes wrong, but then it's more debugging than storing log.
- you don't want to mix business data (users, transaction, etc...) with not so important / relevant data
- the amount of log is too important for your current system and putting them in a database might crash it completly
- you might want to use another system to dig into the log, with a different typoe of storage (haddop, big data, nosql )
- when you do database backup, you usually backup all the database. Logs are not 'as important' as other critical data, are bigger, and then would take too much place
- there is no need to always put logs in database. Using plain text and some other tools (web server log for instance) is usually more than enough.

So that's for these reason that logs are in general not stored in the same database than the application.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.With the information you provided I now can understand what is missing in my question. Think of my database like server a place where log data from all atms,banks goes into. Do not think it like mysql,oracle. As i said it is a bank's server and flow rate is too high.The problem is that some logs are not stored and the question is how to find the possible reasons behind that and possible solutions to them and how to detect if this problem occurs. Any kind of help would be appreciated